# hdmi cable to lcd tv

Tags: lcd, hdmi

I have an hdmi out on my motherboard, and an lcd with two hdmi inputs.
Up until several days ago everything worked fine with regards to seeing movies on the TV, and when the audio was directed to Digital Audio device I'd hear it from the TV.
After a bad incident involving ripping the cable out of its socket and destroying it, I had to buy new hdmi cable. Now I can only ge the picture on hdmi2 (before it was through hdmi1), and I get no sound on the TV.
I figured there are 4 major cases:
1. the computer digital output is damaged
2. the tv digital audio input is damaged
3. hdmi1 on the tv is damaged, and hdmi2 was never supopsed to have an audio channel (is it possible?)
4. the cheap hdmi cable I bought only handles video, and no audio (again - I don't even know if such video-only cables exist)

Which option is the most logical? How can I strike out several to get to the bottom of this?

I run windows7 here, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay logical deduction:

- Lend someones laptop and test out your el-cheapo HDMI cable on a other tv with another laptop (ruling out the HDMI cable)
- Use that laptop tot test your TV + HDMI cable (ruling out your TV input being damaged)

if those two still work, most likely cause is our computer digital output. You could verify that again with another tv.

If all those test work... Than it might be an unlucky combination of HDMI cable + tv/pc .. Check the specs of your cable, tv and computer to be sure.. (Thats a last resort)

Comment: I guess that will have to do. Just need to find someone with an hdmi enabled laptop, and someone with an hdmi tv. Not that many around me.
Thanks for the tips.